# he hecho una app que usa base SQLite pero no al presionar el botón de login no pasa nada

Tags: java, android, android-studio, base-de-datos, sqlite

he hecho una app que se supone que debería hacer un login de usuarios mediante SQLite, la app guarda los datos en la base de datos y todo, pero cuando quiero hacer login al tocar el botón de login no pasa nada, ni error ni nada, no se que he hecho mal, aqui dejo el codigo de la clase MainActivity y la de SQLite_OpenHelper para ver si alguien me indica si estoy haciendo algo mal :(

```
package com.xcore.xserver.link;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import OpenHelper.SQLite_OpenHelper;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnLogin;
    Button btnregaccess;
    EditText loginboxEmail;
    EditText loginboxPasswort;

    SQLite_OpenHelper helper=new SQLite_OpenHelper(this,"ConfidentialDB",null,1);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnregaccess= (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);

        btnregaccess.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent regintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Register.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(regintent);

        }
        });

        btnLogin=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 loginboxEmail=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginbox_email);
                 loginboxPasswort=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginbox_passwort);

                try {
                    Cursor cursor=helper.verifyuserpass(loginboxEmail.getText().toString(),loginboxPasswort.getText().toString());

                    if (cursor.getCount()>0) {
                        Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),homepage.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"correo y/o contraseña incorrectos",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    loginboxEmail.setText("");
                    loginboxPasswort.setText("");
                    loginboxEmail.findFocus();

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Aqui esta la clase de SQLite_OpenHelper

```
package OpenHelper;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class SQLite_OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public SQLite_OpenHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query="create table usersregist(_ID integer primary key autoincrement, Vorname text, Straße text, Email text, Passwort text);";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    // open database
    public void opendb(){
        this.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    // close database
    public void closedb(){
        this.close();
    }

    // insert regist on db
    public void insertreg(String vor, String str, String ema, String pas){
        ContentValues valors=new ContentValues();
        valors.put("Vorname",vor);
        valors.put("Straße",str);
        valors.put("Email",ema);
        valors.put("Passwort",pas);
        this.getWritableDatabase().insert("usersregist",null,valors);
    }

    // verify if the user exist on the database
    public Cursor verifyuserpass(String usu, String pas) throws SQLException{
        Cursor mcursor=null;
        mcursor=this.getReadableDatabase().query("usersregist",new String[]{"_ID","Vorname","Straße","Email","Passwort"},"Correo like '"+usu+"' and Password like '"+pas+"'",null,null,null,null);
        return mcursor;

    }


}
```

Esta es la clase Register, por si puede ser de ayuda

```
package com.xcore.xserver.link;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import OpenHelper.SQLite_OpenHelper;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnreginsert;
    EditText RegboxEmail, RegboxStraße, RegboxPasswort, RegboxVorname;

    SQLite_OpenHelper helper=new SQLite_OpenHelper(this,"ConfidentialDB",null,1);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        btnreginsert=(Button) findViewById(R.id.registdb);
        RegboxEmail=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.regbox_email);
        RegboxStraße=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.regbox_straße);
        RegboxPasswort=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.regbox_passwort);
        RegboxVorname=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.regbox_vorname);

        btnreginsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                helper.opendb();
                helper.insertreg(String.valueOf(RegboxVorname.getText()),
                        String.valueOf(RegboxStraße.getText()),
                        String.valueOf(RegboxEmail.getText()),
                        String.valueOf(RegboxPasswort.getText()));
                helper.closedb();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Registrado Correctamente"
                        ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Que error te saca ya que sino hace nada algun error dara.

Comment: Cuando haces click en el botón ¿entra en el OnClickListener? Pon el debugger alguna traza de log.

Comment: abri el logcat pero solamente sale "E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
    SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length" lo demas bien

Comment: solucione el problema cambiando "Correo" por Email y "usu" por ema, igual gracias a los que respondieron para ayudarme con el problema.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Prueba cambiando la consulta que estás realizando por:

```
String[] parametros = {usu, pas};    
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM usersregist WHERE Correo = ? AND 
Password = ? ", parametros);
```

Comment: u.u no se donde cambiar eso :(, en el mainactivity o el SQLite_openhelper activity

Comment: En el openHelper en verifyuserpass, cambias el cursor que ya tienes.

Comment: me da error, creo que mejor buscare otra forma de hacer login mediante SQLite

Comment: Qué error te sale?

Comment: illegal line end in string literal. ":" expected. ";" expected.

Comment: listo, lo solucione cambiando el "Correo" por Email y el "usu" por ema